# Difference between games services and application

Tags: android, google-play-services

I've made an app that using google play games services. I'm looking at the developers console now, and I see two tabs...

[image]

The top one is Applications and the one below it is Games Services. It seems that I can fill out both and publish both. I don't want to make any rash decisions before I know what these do exactly. Can some one help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Applications tab is for publishing apps/games (using **apk** files) to Android. These will show up in the Play store.

The Games Services is for configuring your Games Services **for all platforms** - this includes achievements, leaderboards, etc. These are done separately from the Android app because the same information can be used for multiple platforms, so your Android, iOS, and web versions share the exact same achievements, leaderboards, etc.

This means that for an Android app you will need to complete **both** of these sections and publish them. However, you can also setup the Games Services only and link them to, for example, a web app, without creating a matching entry in Applications.

Comment: Ah I see, So after I upload my apk in the applications section, I have to link the "app" from the games services sections so it uses all the achievements and stuff I've done?

Comment: Exactly :) Have a look at [this article](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling), it describes the process fairly well.

Comment: That article says "publish the Play Games services settings first before you publish your game", but it is not clear about the required steps to do that. It would be good to see a step-by-step document.